# Let $\mu$ be the semicircle in the first two quadrants with radius $R$. Why is the length of $\mu\cap \{y > \sqrt{R} \}$ $\le 4\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-integration

As part of an example where $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x}~dx$ is calculated using Complex Analysis and the Residue theorem, my textbook casually states that where $\mu_R^4(t) = R e^{i t}$ for $o \le t \le \pi$,
$$
\mathrm{length}(\mu_R^4 \cap \{ z : y < \sqrt{R} \}) \le 4 \sqrt{R}
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{length}(\mu_R^4 \cap \{z : y \ge \sqrt{R} \}) \le \pi R.
$$

Obviously in the second case, the length of the whole semicircle $\mu_R^4$ is precisely $\pi R$, but I do not see how the first estimate was achieved. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: How rigorous are you trying to be? Just looking in the first quadrant, it's clearly true that the length of the arc from $y=0$ up to $y=\sqrt{R}$ is less than the length along the $L$-shaped path (two sides of the square) that has length $2\sqrt{R}$. Look [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1bwi9hw548), and drag the $R$ slider to modify the radius if you like.

Comment: @SammyBlack Tysm, this helps a lot. I didn't realize that they were just finding a rough upper bound on the length.